# How do I execute these 2 different blocks of code in a sequence in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

this is the code from my route:

```
const hotspots = await Hotspot.find({user: req.user._id});
    if(!hotspots) return res.render("hotspot");
    let hotspotData = [];
    let rewards = [];
function getApiData(){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            let error = false;
            for (let hotspot of hotspots){
                axios.get(`https://api.helium.io/v1/hotspots/${hotspot.hotspot}`)
                    .then((resp)=>hotspotData.push(resp.data));
                
                axios.get(`https://api.helium.io/v1/hotspots/${hotspot.hotspot}/rewards/sum`)
                    .then((resp)=> {
                        console.log("first console log",resp.data.data.total)
                        rewards.push(resp.data.data.total) ;
                        console.log("Data gained from axios",resp.data.data.total);
                    })
                
            }
            if(!error) resolve();
            else reject("Something went wrong");
        })
    }

 getApiData().then(()=> {
        console.log(hotspotData);
        console.log(rewards);
        res.render("hotspot",{hotspots: hotspotData, rewards: rewards});
    });
```

Everything else is fine, but when I'm logging `hotspotData` and `rewards`, I'm getting an empty array but as you can see I've already pushed the data I got from APIs to those arrays respectively. But sti;; I'm getting empty array. Please help me. I have logged the API data and yes it's sending the correct data but I don't know why that data does not get pushed to the arrays.

Edit: This is the output which suggests my code is not getting executed in the way I want it to:

[image: output]

Comment: check how the event loop works, and how to use async/await instead of promises, it will make your code easier to read too

Comment: This promise-approach is working fine. It's just that the data is not getting pushed to the array and idk why

Comment: It doesn't work because the promise approach is not working hehe
Let me write a couple examples in an answer, give me a bit of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that the code that sends back the response is executed before the axios responses arrive:

- First, a call to a database (is that correct?) using a async/await approach.
- Then you define a function that returns a Promise and call it processing the response in the `then()` function.
- That piece of code is executed when the Promise is `resolve()`d (watch out there's no code to handle a rejected response).
- Now the promise is resolved once the `for` loop ends, it doesn't wait
  for the `axios` promises to return, it just triggers the requests and
  continue. **The code block after they return will be run in another moment.**

If you want to solve this, one thing you could do is to use async/await everywhere, and make the calls sequentially, something like this:

```js
const hotspots = await Hotspot.find(...);

function async getApiData() {
    let hotspotData = [];
    let rewards = [];
    for loop {
        hotspot = await axios.get(hotspot)
        reward = await axios.get(reward)
        ...
        // add both to the arrays
    }
    return { hotspotData, rewards }
}

const { hotspotData, rewards } = await getApiData();
console.log(hotspotData);
console.log(rewards);
res.render("hotspot",{hotspots: hotspotData, rewards: rewards});
```

Note: the code above is more pseudo-code than real javascript ok?

I think this could be an interesting read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Also, notice all the axios calls seem to be independent from each other, so perhaps you can run them asynchronously, and wait for all promises to be resolved to continue. Check this out for more info about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all
(make sure it works sequentially, first)

I think it should be something like an array of promises (one per hotspot and reward in the `for` loop), then returning something like:

```js
return Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
```

Comment: I tried this but both arrays are undefined now.

Comment: Do you know if something failed inside the `getApiData()` call?

Comment: remember the code above is not to copy&paste, it is pseudo-code just to show the idea, ok?

Comment: yeah I know. I didn't copy-paste it. But the result of both api calls is now undefined.

Comment: can you debug that code? check what is the final url that is been called, and the what it returns

Comment: The URL that has been called, when I simply visit it with the browser, returns the correct data. But, in my code the variable is being returned as undefined. I'm making the call like so:

`let {reward} = await axios.get(`https://api.helium.io/v1/hotspots/${hotspot.hotspot}/rewards/sum`);`

But the variable reward is undefined.

Comment: So, now I tried making request like so: 
`let reward = axios.get.....` and it works now. Thank you so much for helping me. Thanks

Comment: whoaaa nice to hear that!! congrats!!